# Stacking symbologies in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, symbology

I'm trying to figure out how to show some stacked symbology. What I am trying to show is stratigraphy on a plan map to help me do some mapping. The way I have it setup up is I have is 1 point location with 1 or more points in sequence on that location (see figure). For example. Location 1:1:sand; 1:2:gravel, 1:3:till, etc... I would like to be able to show this on the map as say a yellow square over a orange square over a blue square. is there any way to really do this? I'm happy to clarify further if need be. PS. I can use either ArcGIS Pro 2.6 or ArcMap 10.8

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want to be exploring [attribute-driven symbology](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/attribute-driven-symbology.htm)?

Comment: Some soil mappers use dot density symbology. There are a lot of articles out there on this problem.